# Audio does not stop playing when target lost - AR App with Vuforia 10.20.3

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm building an AR app with vuforia latest version 10.20.3. I want to play video when click on collider on target found. If target lost, then it should stop video and its audio also. But, I'm facing a problem that when target lost, it stops showing video but does not stop audio. The audio continues to play. I don't know why..?
I have added the video on plane, and there in (in Inspector panel), in video player options, I've set audio to none, and then added another audio source and provide it audio clip. And it is not working.
Previously, I have tried to give audio in video player 'direct' (in inspector panel) and also tried with audio source (given in video player). But I face same issue again and again. The audio won't stop playing when target lost.
Please provide me the code for finding trackable or not in Vuforia 10.20.3. Or is there any checkbox that can stop audio when target lost. Please provide me an answer that can be applicable for latest version. Please answer. Thanks.

Comment: You need to get a reference of the `AudioSource` and call `AudioSource.Stop()` when the target is lost. Even if your `AudioSource` is on the target, it won't stop playing automatically, you have to tell it to do so. Is that your problem or are you struggling with how to do sth if the target is lost? For that you implement your behavior via `OnTargetLost()` exposed by the `DefaultObserverStatusEventHandler`